# JavaScript ASP.Net MVC redirection with object

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

How can i use JavaScript to redirect to a controller that launch a page based on a sent object.

In MVC we do something like this

```
return View("RegistrationConfirmation", registrationIsasViewModel);
```

How would I accomplish this same thing using JavaScript. 
**Note**

I do not want to sen the data to WebApi controller.

If the WebApi can return the view I need we can use it
I need to be able to call the controller so that it returns the view.

Comment: you can open a new window/tab using javscript. But do not think about passing an object. Consider passing the minimum data needed (Ex : Querystring key/values - primary key of the enitty). remember, there is a a limit in querystrings.

Comment: You're asking to have client-side coding perform server-side actions. You should develop a backend API that the javascript can hit to then fire off something on the backend. Or simply just have the javascript redirect you to another View that you already have predefined. Why are you against the API??

Comment: Not quite, I need Java script to call the controller that and send the object, the controller will then take over and carry out the actions along with returning the view i need

Comment: Can the Web Api return a view i need? if so I'm open to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript in your usage, would be strictly client side.  You've provided no evidence, that your utilizing a front-end framework that can actually have server side pre-proccessing.  With that being said, you have two options:

- JavaScript redirect to another page, utilizing the query string.
- Ajax, the controller with a post method with a returned JavaScript result.

Those are your only real options, both aren't ideal in most cases.

**Update:**

```
$.ajax({
    ...    
});
```

Then on the server, you would have the controller:

```
return JavaScript("window.location = ....");
```

The server would be basically sending a redirect to the other page, but the actions of that controller would be lost, unless you store in a cache of some sort, before the next page renders on the redirect.

Comment: So I wouldn't be able to render the model on the new page?

Comment: @C.Robin You would, basically the page loads.  User does something, you send the data to the server via Ajax, it process the data, then when it returns the redirect, the controller for that new page would execute.  Any model data you want to return, can be returned.  That new controller would be loading the new model data.  If that new controller needs the model from previous controller, you would need to cache it so the new controller can access.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using Json Object. Make an ajax request to the controller and return Json object. On success redirect to another page using window.location.href

This http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-return-json-nested-sub-object-from-controller-in-mvc will help you to understand it more in detail.

Comment: I think he is trying to do a $.ajax({ ... }); but have the controller basically return a redirect.  Which is possible, as JavaScript object to have the server do what it needs for the object model and load page.

Comment: Yes this sounds about right, how would I carry this out? @Greg